# Where do child navigation options appear from Durandal's createChildRouter?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, durandal, hottowel

I am trying to figure out how to properly use createChildRouter. After going in circles for a day and a half trying to find code that will give me some results, I have settled for the moment on the following code (which still doesn't give me results):

### shell.js

```
var routes = [
      { route: '', moduleId: 'home', title: 'Home', nav: 1 },
      { route: 'inventory/*index', moduleId: 'inventory/inventory', title: 'Inventory', nav: 2 }];

return router.makeRelative({ moduleId: 'viewmodels' }) // router will look here for viewmodels by convention
      .map(routes)            // Map the routes
      .buildNavigationModel() // Finds all nav routes and readies them
      .activate();            // Activate the router
```

### inventory.js

```
define(['services/logger', 'plugins/router'], function (logger, router) {
      var title = 'Details';
      var childRouter = router.createChildRouter()
      .makeRelative({
         moduleId: 'viewmodels/inventory',
         fromParent: true
      }).map([
            { route: 'index', moduleId: 'inventory', title: 'Inventory', nav: 3 },
            { route: 'inventory', moduleId: 'items', title: 'Items', nav: 4 }])
         .buildNavigationModel();
      var vm = {
         router: childRouter,
         activate: activate,
         title: title
      };

      return vm;

      //#region Internal Methods
      function activate() {
         logger.log(title + ' View Activated', null, title, true);
      }
      //#endregion
});
```

My tree structure looks like this:

[image: DurandalProjectTree]

Because of my failure to get any results, I'm starting to suspect that it's not my routing code that is the problem, but rather my navigation menu or perception of how/whether child routers are supposed to appear and be visible without additional work. I'm using a plain vanilla template (hot towel) and the only thing I've changed is the logging code in router.js because I'm trying to figure out what the router code is looking for. The result I get from the above code (with my modified logging) is as follows when I click on the button to switch from my "Home" view to my "Inventory" view:

```
LOG: /^$/ != inventory/*index 
LOG: /^inventory\/(.*?)$/ == inventory/*index 
LOG: Activating[object Object] 
LOG: [Details] Details View Activated 
LOG: Navigation Complete[object Object][object Object] 
LOG: /^index$/ != *index 
LOG: /^inventory$/ != *index 
LOG: Route '*index' Not Found
```

So my questions are, is this what the routing code is *supposed* to do? Is it *supposed* to fail to match the splat route with any of the child routes? Do I need to do something to make navigation buttons for the child routes appear? Were they supposed to appear automatically? My view *does* switch to inventory.js/html, but no new navigation buttons appear when this happens.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [knockout samples](https://github.com/BlueSpire/Durandal/blob/master/platforms/Microsoft.NET/Samples/Durandal.Samples/App/ko/index.js) for a working implementation of child routes. Child routes will NOT be added to the primary navigation if that's what you're expecting. They are intended to be used with a secondary navigation. The HTML version can be seen live at http://dfiddle.github.io/dFiddle-2.0/#knockout-samples.

Comment: The link you provided takes me to the router code, but what I think I'm really missing is the secondary navigation code. Can you give me any tips of implementing secondary navigation?

Comment: Check [index.html](https://github.com/BlueSpire/Durandal/blob/master/platforms/Microsoft.NET/Samples/Durandal.Samples/App/ko/index.html) in the same directory. `introSamples` and `detailedSamples` are the two filtered child router arrays that will be used in a simple `ko foreach`. No magic involved. BTW: What is the `makeRelative` good for in shell.js?

Comment: You're guess is better than mine on the use of makeRelative in shell.js. I pulled that straight out of the hot towel template at https://github.com/johnpapa/HotTowel/blob/master/NuGet/HotTowel/App/viewmodels/shell.js

Comment: Every foreach that I see in that index.html is commented out. Please excuse my extreme noob-ness, but I have not written a web app since before the days of jQuery so I'm learning a lot all at once here. Is there some "magic" going on in the parsing of comments?

Comment: Missed the hot towel part, sorry. I'll have to start a visual studio machine to see how @JohnPapa has implemented this.

Comment: You might consider starting here http://learn.knockoutjs.com/ to get the basics of knockout covered. Durandal delegates to requirejs when it comes to module handling/looading and to knockout for template binding. In order to build Durandal apps you need to familiarize with those to a certain degree. Head over to pluralsight @JohnPapa has some good courses that cover these.

Comment: I've completely walked through the first 3 tutorials and skimmed the last two (for now) and I don't see anything that explains how the index.html that you linked to is working. Don't you need to have a foreach in a data-bind attribute somewhere to bind to a collection?

Comment: Finally Googled "ko foreach" and found http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html which explains it.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19940661/how-to-use-durandals-createchildrouter